# How to determine the relative path to a file from within an asp.net mvc3 area

Tags: asp.net, view, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to know what's the best way using the Razor syntax to determine the relative path to the ClientBin folder from within an Area's View.

Thank you,
Stephen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by luck, I had been using the first multi-line expression, then by chance went back to the second one.. Has nothing to do with the mapping of the file, or where it's running from

```
<div>
    @{
        com.patten.root.Helpers.Silverlight.SilverlightHost("/ClientBin/jounce.xap");  
    }
</div>

<div>
    @com.patten.root.Helpers.Silverlight.SilverlightHost("/ClientBin/jounce.xap");
</div>
```